# bootstrap carousel navigation menu adjustments dont work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, carousel

I am using a bootstrap carousel and want it to look like this

[image]

The Problem is, since I am not getting the navigation menu to look like this. Only when I delete the class 'carousel-indicators' it looks pretty much, as I want to, but then if it auto-slides the active-class of the navigation does not work. Do you have any Solution for that?

Here is my code without the class .carousel-indicators: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lta9vra/1/

I've tried like this without success:

```
    .carousel-indicators {
          all: initial;
          * {
            all: unset;
          }
        }

    .carousel-indicators.carousel-indicators li {
    text-indent: 0;
        border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Here including the class and some adjustmens, which crashes the navigation:  https://jsfiddle.net/7Lta9vra/2/

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/wkjrL8anzN